# Getting first enum as always selected from radiobutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have three radio button but when i select EFG and post it to controller I always get ABC in Selected property.

View

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selected, AllEnum.ABC) <label>ABC</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selected, AllEnum.EFG)<label>EFG</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selected, AllEnum.QWE)<label>QWE</label>
```

Model

```
public AllEnum Selected{ get; set; }
```

can you help me out in getting selected radiobutton value in controller.

Comment: Show your model. What is `Selected`?

Comment: public AllEnum Selected{ get; set; }

Comment: The model is fine, so its something you have not shown us that is causing the issue. What is your controller code? Do you have a hidden input for `Selected` in the view as well?

Comment: And just as a side note - you should use `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selected, AllEnum.ABC, new { id = "" })<span>ABC</span></label>` so the label is associated with the button, and you remove the (duplicate) `id` attributes

Comment: no hidden input and simple model as parameter in controller

Comment: Based on the limited information you have given, you code will work fine and will bind correctly. We cannot help further unless you create a [mcve] which reproduces your problem

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code.

**Model**

```
public enum AllEnum
{
    ABC,
    EFG,
    QWE
}

public class SimpleModel
{
    public AllEnum Selected { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SimpleModel();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SimpleModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@using SimpleMVC.Models
@model SimpleMVC.Models.SimpleModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selected, AllEnum.ABC) <label>ABC</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selected, AllEnum.EFG)<label>EFG</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Selected, AllEnum.QWE)<label>QWE</label>

    <input type="submit" />
}
```